# there is a gap between two relative layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

There is a gap between two Relative Layouts. I want to remove this gap.

[image: this is the image of the above xml]

My xml of the image is given below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/live_view_surface_view_rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/video_height">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/palette_rl">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </SurfaceView>        
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/palette_rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/transperent_black_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/snapshot_button_rl"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/snapshotselection" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mic_btn_rl_parent"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/snapshot_button_rl"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mic_button_rl"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mic_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/talkbackbtn_selector" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/start_talkback_progress"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/field_width_small"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/field_width_small"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/live_view_audio_icon_rl"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/field_width_medium"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/live_view_audio_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_volume" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This gap remains same even i increase the height of the below relative layout.
Both layouts have same parent but still they are not ajusted in the same.

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: @Nisarg this is my xml

Comment: now good let me check

Comment: this is space by given your height  android:layout_height="60dp" please avoid hard code

Comment: @AditayKaushal can you suggest what should i use instead?

Comment: @UserSharma i am leaving office now , but  one easy solution is make  parent layout  as Linear-layout  of both and  give weight  to both 8 and 2 inner relative layouts , Hope will work

Comment: @AditayKaushal  your idea is not working in my case i tried it.

Comment: give me 5 min i try your code

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just Copy Paste and write your xml inside Relative Layout

```
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8">

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: replace your video height  with match_parent and palette_rl layout also a match_parent

Answer (score 0):

set weightsum=1 to parent layout(palette_rl).after set weight=0.25 to all child Relative layout and keep it's layout_width=0dip.it works fine.adjust all space in same order.

please use below xml.I changed height and dimension and drawable. so,please adjust it.it works fine.black line removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/live_view_surface_view_rl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </SurfaceView>        
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/palette_rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ab00aa">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/snapshot_button_rl"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mic_btn_rl_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/snapshot_button_rl"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mic_button_rl"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mic_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/start_talkback_progress"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_view_audio_icon_rl"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/live_view_audio_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have a problem in heights of the layouts the black strip between two layouts is in their height

Comment: i added xml file in answer.